# How can we populate textarea value when textarea is initilized as ckeditor

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, ckeditor

Well i have been working on CKEDITOR with HTML FORMS and backend is asp.net core v3.1. I have used asp tag helpers in rendering and binding html forms.

Following is the code :

```
 <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="Content" class="control-label"></label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                
                                    <textarea asp-for="Content" class="form-control" required placeholder="Content"></textarea>
                                    <span asp-validation-for="Content" class="text-danger"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

I have two pages create and edit which creates the first form entry to database and update the values respectively.

So when i load edit page all the values are loaded but CKEditor values are not loaded after all it is bound to textarea.

Values are not displaying in HTML CKEDITOR content area.

```
CKEDITOR INITILIZE CODE IS BELOW

  <script>
        // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
        // instance, using default configuration.
        $(function () {
         CKEDITOR.replace('Content');        
        })
       
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API documentation has documented methods for this:

1. #### Set Data

   [setData](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#method-setData).

```js
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData( '<p>This is the editor data.</p>' );
```

2. #### Insert Element

   [insertElement](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#method-insertElement).

```js
var element = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml( '<img src="hello.png" border="0" title="Hello" />' );
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.insertElement( element );
```

3. #### Insert Text

   [insertText](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#method-insertText).

```js
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.insertText( ' line1 \n\n line2' );
```

4. #### Insert Html

   [insertHtml](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#method-insertHtml).

```js
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.insertHtml( '<p>This is a new paragraph.</p>' );
```

I think what you need is `setData` as the other methods append text/html at the cursor position.